# How to download a file from a link which is javascript enabled, in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net, web-scraping

I have a list of weblinks in a list. I want to go to every link in the list and download a file from the opened website which is another link on the opened page and is javascript enabled!

The list of weblinks are like this:

```
['"http://www.energychoice.ohio.gov/ApplesToApplesComparision.aspx?Category=Electric&TerritoryId=2&RateCode=1"', ]
```

and more links similar to the shown are in the list.

I need to go to every link which will open a website and that would have the download file "Export offers to XML". This link is javascript enabled.

I am a newbie in Python. I am using python 2.7 on ubuntu.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look at the link content for file download:

   `<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkExportToExcel" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkExportToExcel&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Export offers to XML</a>` Here comes the **__doPostBack()** js function.
2. I've found this function in code: 
   `<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
   if (!theForm) {
       theForm = document.aspnetForm;
   }
   function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
       if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
           theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
           theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
           theForm.submit();
       }
   }
   //]]>
   </script>`
      Where it's obviously the function submits a form. Form id is **aspnetForm**.
3. I found this form in the code too:`<form method="post" action="ApplesToApplesComparision.aspx?Category=Electric&amp;TerritoryId=2&amp;RateCode=1" id="aspnetForm">
   <div class="aspNetHidden">
   <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
   <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
   <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="qqEqj+MJZCXWWypTsbeT2OudaHSwkSmxn4MMtBuWopgD50psDlTzoVSH0gMVRNktX7EW7I2uWKnF9IzD8/BkloDdz+4OSdWS7MbiJaQ2KVBHoZCFqMN0IgLe82fkuPJxk/wf1h/ZWYjOwi5XRTLZEy4JKRc...`

   > Dealing with ASP.NET remember they **try to save/handle state of HTTP requests in a special variable: `__VIEWSTATE`**. So each request (to and fro) this variable (input field in a form) is getting changed (increasing). Therefore it's vital to send requests thru this very form with `__VIEWSTATE`.
4. I recommend you to simulate a form in python, it having been loaded with parameters from a needed link and especially with parameter `__VIEWSTATE` from the real form of a scraped page. See below the shot with important info on the clicking a link and following form submit:[image]

Comment: I am able to perform the task in different way! First i am opening new web browser from the list of url one by one using a for loop. Then i searched the downloading element using the xpath. I am able to click on the element also but i am facing another issue with the file name. As all the downloaded file are of same name so it is overwriting the previous downloaded file! I need to rename the file name while downloading.

Comment: I am again facing a similar issue with the link "http://mciindia.org/InformationDesk/CollegesCoursesSearch.aspx" In this page i have to extract all the table contents and even have to navigate through the pages. Kindly help!

Comment: @newbie, have you succeded with a JS form emulating or POST request in Python? Expose what you've already tried.